# Crear Json con datos de una tabla

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo la sienguiente tabla que se llena al realizar una fórmula
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que debo hacer es que al darle clic en un botón para exportar me cree un json con el código y la cantidad, y se lo pongo a una función. Esto es lo que tengo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.exportar').click(function(){

    var imgData = canvas = document.getElementById($(this).attr('rel')).toDataURL("image/png");
    var pdf = new jsPDF;
    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
    var download = $('.exportar');
     pdf.save("download.pdf");   

      jsonObj = [];
      $("table[class=rc]").each(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('.muestra');
        var codigo = $(this).val();

        item = {}
        item [".muestra"] = id;
        item [".codpex"] = codigo;
        jsonObj.push(item);
      });
      console.log(jsonObj);

  var scope = window.parent.angular.element(window.frameElement).scope();
  scope.$ctrl.procesarLineas(jsonObj);
  scope.$apply();
  });
});
```

muestra es la clase del campo código y codepex el la clase de cantidad.

asi es la tabla

```
**<table class="rc">
<tr>
    <th >Código</th>
    <th >Cantidad</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td  id='codpcentral' class='codpcentralx'></td> 
<td  id='npcentral' class='npcentralx'></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>**
```

Comment: te recomiendo crear un string del objeto y luego utilizar la función JSON.parse() para convertir en objeto JSON, ej: **var oJSON=JSON.parse('{"id":"0001"}')**

Comment: A lo expresado por fwBasic; añado sería mires que este obteniendo bien el dato; no veo (directamente) que te ocurre (falla 'cual?, datos vacios/undefined,..); te comento salvo el "$("table[class=rc]")" te devuelva cada "tr" del "tbody" de la tabla hasta ahí "bien" (creo) pero el "attr(".muestra")"  y el "$(this).val()" me parece no hacen referencia a ninguna celda (TD) de la tabla. Añade código html del TABLE al menos uno o dos reglones depues del encabezado (lo que esta en negrillas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el siguiente código muestra como convertir una tabla a un objeto JSON:

```js
var json="";
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#export").on("click",function () {
  $("table tbody tr").each(function () {
   json ="";
   $(this).find("td").each(function () {
    $this=$(this);
      json+=',"'+$this.attr("class")+'":"'+$this.html()+'"'
   });
   obj=JSON.parse('{'+json.substr(1)+'}');
   console.log(obj);
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="rc">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Código</th>
   <th>Cantidad</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class='codigo'>1</td> 
   <td class='numero'>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class='codigo'>2</td> 
   <td class='numero'>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class='codigo'>3</td> 
   <td class='numero'>30</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<button id="export">Exportar</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Un ejemplo de como acceder al contenido de cada celda de la tabla conforme a la estructura que pusiste puedes verlo aquí [realizado](https://jsfiddle.net/mm0j6cco/)

Enfocándome solo a la parte JavaScript<->jQuery prueba lo siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.exportar').click(function(){

    var imgData = canvas = document.getElementById($(this).attr('rel')).toDataURL("image/png");
    var pdf = new jsPDF;
    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
    var download = $('.exportar');
     pdf.save("download.pdf");   

      jsonObj = [];
      $("table tbody tr").each(function(){
        var elitem ="{\"muestra\": " + $('.codpcentralx', this).html() + ", \"codpec\": " + $('.npcentralx', this).html() + "}";
        jsonObj.push(JSON.parse(elitem));
      });
      <!-- como tu petición es del JSON lo demás fuera del "each" a los "TR" del Table no son parte de la respuesta ni evalue -->
      console.log(jsonObj);

  var scope = window.parent.angular.element(window.frameElement).scope();
  scope.$ctrl.procesarLineas(jsonObj);
  scope.$apply();
  });
});
```